# QTextLayout::drawCursor() does not work when subclassing QAbstractTextDocumentLayout

Tags: qt, qtextedit, qtextdocument

currently `QTextEdit` and `QPlainTextEdit` does not meet my requirements, so I need to subclass `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout` to provide custom layout of the document. I reference `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` and `QTextDocumentLayout` a lot, and finally got a simple layout to display the text. However, I couldn't see the cursor in `QTextEdit`, which should be blinking. I need help to figure this out.

I am using Qt 5.9.1. The simple project is [here](https://github.com/tamlok/VTextEdit). The `draw()` function of `VTextDocumentLayout` looks like this:

```
void VTextDocumentLayout::draw(QPainter *p_painter, const PaintContext &p_context)
{
    qDebug() << "VTextDocumentLayout draw()" << p_context.clip << p_context.cursorPosition << p_context.selections.size();
    // Find out the blocks.
    int first, last;
    blockRangeFromRect(p_context.clip, first, last);
    if (first == -1) {
        return;
    }

    QTextDocument *doc = document();
    QPointF offset(m_margin, m_blocks[first].m_offset);
    QTextBlock block = doc->findBlockByNumber(first);
    QTextBlock lastBlock = doc->findBlockByNumber(last);
    qreal maximumWidth = m_width;

    while (block.isValid()) {
        const BlockInfo &info = m_blocks[block.blockNumber()];
        const QRectF &rect = info.m_rect;
        QTextLayout *layout = block.layout();

        if (!block.isVisible()) {
            offset.ry() += rect.height();
            if (block == lastBlock) {
                break;
            }

            block = block.next();
            continue;
        }

        QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = block.blockFormat();
        QBrush bg = blockFormat.background();
        if (bg != Qt::NoBrush) {
            fillBackground(p_painter, rect, bg);
        }

        auto selections = formatRangeFromSelection(block, p_context.selections);

        QPen oldPen = p_painter->pen();
        p_painter->setPen(p_context.palette.color(QPalette::Text));

        layout->draw(p_painter,
                     offset,
                     selections,
                     p_context.clip.isValid() ? p_context.clip : QRectF());

        // Draw the cursor.
        int blpos = block.position();
        int bllen = block.length();
        bool drawCursor = p_context.cursorPosition >= blpos
                          && p_context.cursorPosition < blpos + bllen;

        Q_ASSERT(p_context.cursorPosition >= -1);
        if (drawCursor) {
            int cpos = p_context.cursorPosition;
            cpos -= blpos;

            qDebug() << "draw cursor" << block.blockNumber() << blpos << bllen << p_context.cursorPosition << cpos;
            layout->drawCursor(p_painter, offset, cpos);
        }

        p_painter->setPen(oldPen);

        offset.ry() += rect.height();
        if (block == lastBlock) {
            break;
        }

        block = block.next();
    }
}
```

I called `layout->drawCursor()` to draw the cursor but this function seems to do nothing.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Update:
Add the log as following:

```
VTextDocumentLayout draw() QRectF(67,0 9x13) 19 0
block range 0 1
draw cursor 1 5 15 19 14
blockBoundingRect() 1 13 QRectF(0,0 75x17)
VTextDocumentLayout draw() QRectF(67,0 9x13) -1 0
block range 0 1
blockBoundingRect() 1 13 QRectF(0,0 75x17)
VTextDocumentLayout draw() QRectF(67,0 9x13) 19 0
```

When running this project in Linux, I coundn't see the cursor. However, when running it in Windows, I could see the cursor but not blinking.

Update:
It seems that `QTextEdit` pass a wrong clip rect to the layout. If I just inserted one line of text (only one block within the document), I could see the blinking cursor. Quite strange!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When subclassing `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`, `blockBoundingRect()` should return the **geometry** of the block, not just the rect as what `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` does.

In one word, `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` provides a **BAD** example for subsclassing `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The default value of `PaintContext` class `cursorPosition` is -1.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstracttextdocumentlayout-paintcontext.html#cursorPosition-var

If any default value is not provided to the cursor position ever (it is a public variable), then my guess is value remains -1, and `drawCursor` is always `false` (as the block position index minimum value is zero in worst case).

Try setting some default value to `PaintContext::cursorPosition`, which may display the cursor.

Comment: Hi! I print the log and could see that the `cursorPosition` alternate between `-1` and `19`, which I think corresponding to the blinking of the cursor. What is strange that I can't see the cursor in Linux but always see the cursor (not blinking) in Windows.

Comment: Could you please help to clone this simple project and run it for a try? I really appreciate you help! :) Thanks!

Comment: Sure will give a try

Comment: It seems that I implemented the `blockBoundingRect()` incorrectly. `QPlainTextDocumentLayout` only returns the bounding rect with both x and y `0`, which is not accepted in `QAbstractTextDocumentLayout`. After returning the geometry rect in the `blockBoundingRect()`, everything seems OK~ Thanks! I will update the question later after I make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

My OS is Windows.

> When running this project in Linux, I coundn't see the cursor. However, when running it in Windows, I could see the cursor but not blinking.

> Update: It seems that QTextEdit pass a wrong clip rect to the layout. If I just inserted one line of text (only one block within the document), I could see the blinking cursor. Quite strange!!!

You need to call update signal at the last of `draw` function.

```
emit QAbstactTextDocumentLayout::update();
```

Yes, as you said, this is quite strange. At the fist some lines, there is no problem. But if you edit documents to some extent, draw function stops. That's because your cursor doesn't come to blink.